# How to Style A Specific Material Select

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm working in an Angular 9 project, using Material.

I have a page that has some material selects, and a material paginator( which uses a dropdown for changing the items per page). I want to modify the style of the mat options in the mat select of the paginator, but I do not want this to affect the other mat selects on the page.

Using this edits all the mat-selects on the page.

```
::ng-deep mat-option:last-child:before {
  content: "All";
  float: left;
  text-transform: none;
  top: 4px;
  position: relative;
}
::ng-deep mat-option:last-child .mat-option-text {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

But I need to specify to only modify the paginator select's options. I've tried adding a class to mat-paginator, but it hasn't worked.

```
<mat-paginator class="myStyleClass" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, dataSource?.filteredData.length]"
      [showFirstLastButtons]="true" (page)="setPaginatorInRoute()" >
    </mat-paginator>
```

I also made a quick https://stackblitz.com/edit/style-specific-mat-select

Is there a way to specify which mat select I'm styling?

Answer (score 1):

ng-deep is deprecates, so you should use component without encapsulation, so:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class CustomComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom',
  templateUrl: './custom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class CustomComponent {}
```

The css classes you have created should encapsulate it within a div with another class and define them this way:

css

```css
.custom-style-paginator-select {
  mat-option:last-child:before {
    content: "All";
    float: left;
    text-transform: none;
    top: 4px;
    position: relative;
  }
  mat-option:last-child .mat-option-text {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="custom-style-paginator-select">
  <mat-paginator class="myStyleClass" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, dataSource?.filteredData.length]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true" (page)="setPaginatorInRoute()" >
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

For more information see:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation

https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme

Comment: Thanks for the details on encapsulation! But I wasn't able to implement this. Adding the above code results in no styles being added to any select. I suppose it because when the mat-select opens, it opens in an overlay div that is separate from the rest of the elements. That overlay doesn't have the `custom-style-paginator-select` or `myStyleClass` classes. Which is why I can either style all mat-select or none.

Answer (score 0):

Here follows an example of **CSS** code:

```
/* -------------- */
/* Other elements */
/* -------------- */
::ng-deep .mdc-list-item:not(.mdc-list-item--selected) {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

::ng-deep .mdc-list-item:not(.mdc-list-item--selected) div {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3); /* Fourth number is for transparency level */
}

::ng-deep .mdc-list-item:not(.mdc-list-item--selected) .mdc-list-    item__primary-text {
    color: red; /* Text color */
}

/* ---------------- */
/* Selected element */
/* ---------------- */
::ng-deep .mdc-list-item--selected {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

::ng-deep .mdc-list-item--selected div {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1); /* Fourth number is for transparency level */
}

::ng-deep .mdc-list-item--selected .mdc-list-item__primary-text {
    color: white; /* Text color */
}
```

[image]